# matplotlib - plot outputs text as paths and cannot be converted to LaTeX by Inkscape

Tags: matplotlib, latex, vector-graphics, inkscape

I have a `matplotlib` plot that I would like to save in a vector graphics format to then use in a LaTeX document.

I normally save it from `matplotlib`, open it with Inkscape and save it as PDF+LaTeX (omit text in PDF and create LaTeX file). 
This can also be achieved with:

```
inkscape  -D -z --file=in.pdf --export-pdf=out.pdf --export-latex
```

However, for the following plot, the text is actually a series of paths. Each letter is separate, resulting in Inkscape not being able to save a different `tex` file.

Why is the text not rendered as text but as paths in the code below? Note that the use of `usetex=True` does not make a difference.

Thanks.

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from matplotlib import rc

#rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='Times New Roman')
rc('font', size='20.0')

mu    = 1.7
sigma = 1.1
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=10000, facecolor='k', edgecolor='k', 
                            normed=True, alpha=0.3, histtype='stepfilled',
                            label='\\noindent Empirical data')
y = lognorm.pdf( bins, sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
plt.xlim( (0,50) )
plt.plot(bins, y, '-', color='k', linewidth=2, label='\\noindent Lognormal curve')
plt.ylim( (0, .15) )
plt.xlabel('my x label')
plt.ylabel('my y label')

plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(os.path.expanduser('~/myfile.svg'))
```

Comment: I don't know why it uses paths in SVG output instead text with font reference, but can't you use PDF output instead SVG? It's a vector format, and fonts are embedded.

Comment: Same problem with PDF output!

Comment: I get expected output - PDF with referenced font and text stream. Try to open the file with LibreOffice Draw for example, and you should be able to see text boxes.

Comment: Same problem, even with LibreOffice Draw each letter has their own box. May I clarify that the problem is not with having or not the right font (my output has in fact the correct font) but having each letter drawn as a path instead of text, which therefore makes the labels not recognised as text.

Comment: Sure, for SVG I too get paths instead text, but for PDF I get correct text: http://i.imgur.com/6JAhJn4.png PDF editing in LO Draw is limited thou, as can be seen. I'm on Windows with Python 2.7 and MPL 1.2.0. Maybe you should try to reset `matplotlibrc` temporarily

Comment: Can you output directly to latex from matplotlib? i.e., `matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True` and the output to PDF?

Comment: @PaulH, I don't need a LaTeX-compiled label in my plot, but a file ``graph.pdf`` and ``graph.pdf_tex`` so that I can insert it into a LaTeX document as a vector graphics figure. I don't think matplotlib can do that, can it? It would be fantastic if it did!

Comment: I have the same workflow you have. So why can't you write your text in Inkscape and, if needs be, change the positions in the .pdf_tex file?

Comment: Because if I regenerate the plot, maybe with some other labels, then I have to re-write the text in Inkscape. Automating the process seems a reasonable motivation. The least I can do manually, the better the solution is. In fact, this works most of the times to me, but it doesn't in the instance provided in the code above. I would like to find out why that is.

Comment: @gozzilli I don't quite understand your workflow (my fault, not yours). So this is a shot in the dark, but does this link help you? http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#pgf-tikz-backend

Comment: @PaulH, I don't think the information in that link addresses directly my question, but it may well be a better approach to what I'm trying to do. So thanks a lot of the link, I will give it a go and post back in this space.

Comment: If you can work something out, I would be very interested to see it. I cannot get the pgf backend to work so I'm stuck with the matplotlib, inkscape combo...

Answer (score 31):

I ran into the same problem and fixed it.

The matplotlib documentation in http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html states that the default value for the parameter `svg.fonttype` is `'path'`, which means that characters will be converted to paths when exporting to svg format.

All I needed to do was add the following line in my script:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
```

This way all characters are embedded correctly, I can now edit the text in Inkscape and export  my figure to pdf+Latex, i.e. a pdf file and a pdf_tex file which I include in my `tex` file.

Comment: You are my hero, just save me hours of work every week. Thanks man! : )

Comment: Oddly, this worked for some of my labels but not others. For instance, it does not work for text that I added by "annotate" or "set_yticks" on a  subplot axes, but it works fine for text added by "set_ylabel" on the same subplot axes.

Comment: For PDF exports, this did the trick: plt.rcParams['pdf.use14corefonts'] = True

Answer (score 8):

Another, more permanent option, is to put

```
svg.fonttype : none
```

in your matplotlibrc
(~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc, for example)